# Creating multiple file groups

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Whats the logic we have to obtain when creating multiple file groups for a database or when we store these files using RAID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have big databases with heavy use. Otherwise it adds no value.

Similar to something I said previously:

- [Multiple Data files and Multiple File Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569467/multiple-data-files-and-multiple-file-groups/4569576#4569576)
- [Would a filegroup with many files located on the same drive outperform if it had just one file on SQL Server 2008 R2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269304/would-a-filegroup-with-many-files-located-on-the-same-drive-outperform-if-it-had/4269411#4269411)

Comment: does creating multiple flies groups is and approach of Database Clustering ?

Comment: @Sudantha: clustering is **very different** to multiple file groups. Different concept, different reason. It's too different to explain in this comment